# Use img to track email opening

Tags: google-apps-script

I have created a script that sends an email containing a hidden `img` with a link of a web app:

```js
var uniqkey =    Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "UTC", "yyMMddHHmmssSSS");
var trackingUrl = "https://script.google.com/a/macros/wizy.io/s/AKfycbxGctgLJeU1aqTpT0G5Nj0I6N65GKJIAvJcJYvdko4/dev";    
<img src="'+ trackingUrl+' ?key="' +uniqkey+ '" style="display:none;"/>
```

Every time a form is submitted, an email is sent with this hidden image. The intention is to track opening of the email, by running a web app that contain this script:

```js
function doGet(e) {
  var key=e.parameter.key;
  Logger.log(key);
  MailApp.sendEmail("maher@wizy.io", "test", key);
}
```

However, I've seen that when the mail is sent the `src` changes to:

```js
<img src="https://ci6.googleusercontent.com/proxy/Oiry89sbJhKLci7KPgJ9E6ZR7uwMxFtx3llzwiBXII5gDfP5wwDbimOy2RX4ZRVr5SyiR4XhIetEJ0p5_4oTX9Z-kwLSL61skprvCeVdIgVdaaFTofhFmlub-4BwJQ0IaBCjRQt6Lpw1FCosN-ERYJvYMip67Mtq2rGJFw=s0-d-e1-ft#https://script.google.com/a/macros/wizy.io/s/AKfycbxGctgLJeU1aqTpT0G5Nj0I6N65GKJIAvJcJYvdko4/dev+?key=" class="CToWUd">
```

... and the script doesn't run when the email is opened. How can I fix this ?

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help (__"why isn't this code working?"__) must include the desired behavior, a _specific problem or error_ and _the shortest code necessary_ to reproduce it __in the question itself__. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

you can't fix it. last year google changed their mail so that all images are mirrored in their own servers to prevent exactly what you are doing (tracking).